# space between radio button and text

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I want to put some space between radio button and text in RadioButtonList. Below is my code:

```
  <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rdbTest" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Text="This is test1"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="This is test2"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="This is test3"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="This is test4"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="This is test5"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

This is how it looks like:

[image]

I want to put more spacing between the radio button and "This is test1" , "This is test2" and so on. I have almost 500 radio buttons on my page.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: just add a css rule for it then. Asp.net is still using HTML as you can see. You can still add your own css stylesheet. You can even reference a custom JS script file.
You can also see an alternative way to reference a custom css in this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23159218/how-to-add-custom-css-files-to-asp-net-mvc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a CSS Class in the header (Adjust the margin value to get desired spacing):

```
<style>
    .radioBL input[type="radio"]
    {
        margin-right:10px;
    }
</style>
```

Then add this in your RadioButtonList tag: `CssClass="radioBL"`

Comment: he already has an Id attached to that list, see `ID="rdbTest"`, just write it like `#rdbTest input[type="radio"]` (Or it does not work this way? :)

Comment: It would work that way as well however if that's not the only list he has it's better to make a class over using the ID

Comment: Yes, makes sense